# How do I add more objects or arrays to data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div tag with a preset data attribute `data-data='{"type":"animal","items":"20"}'` to be processed by function A(). Based on users event, more stuff should be added to data attribute using function B() then finally process with function A()

```
<div id="getInfo" data-data='{"type":"animal","items":"20"}'></div>
```

```
function A() {
   var data = $('#getInfo').data('data');
   //send data to server
}
```

```
function B() {
   var long_lat = user_location_data();
   $('#getInfo').data('data');// add long_lat
}
```

Information in data attribute will be sent to server -> query DB, if user allow us to get their location, users location will be added to data attribute i.e. `data-data='{"type":"animal","items":"20","long":"2.35640","lat":"0.35341"}'` then will be processed, sent to the server.

Comment: What's the question? Show the array or object you're trying to add. Also you're showing these functions but not how they are called. I suggest you try making a JsFiddle to show the problem.

Comment: To add information, you need to turn that JSON text into an object first: `var dataObj = JSON.parse($('#getInfo').data('data'));` Now you can add to it: `dataObj.lat = long_lat.lat;`

Comment: @Chris I am avoiding that rout due to how I choose to keep my code clean, I want to be able to remove that feature without disturbing other functionalities in my app

Comment: so set it to the object and reapply it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add more data to data attribute by doing :

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  var data = $('#getInfo').data('data');
  $('#getInfo').data('data', Object.assign(data, {
   long: 2.35640,
   lat: 0.35341
  }));
  
  console.log('newData', $('#getInfo').data('data'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="getInfo" data-data='{"type":"animal","items":"20"}'></div>
```

Comment: @Kopriwa that looks promising, I'll give it a try.

Comment: You are welcome. You should accept this as an answer if it solve your issue. And you should also consider giving up with jquery which is obselete.

Comment: JQuery is solving a lot of problem, but what will you recommend?

Comment: jquery is not solving any problem anymore. It used to help for selecting component. You can now do the same with vanilla javascript `document.querySelector` and `document.querySelectorAll`. All the JS transitions and animations should be replaced with pure css3.

Comment: I disagree. jQuery is still very useful, especially when it comes to event handling. Until vanilla JS has robust support for similarly short and readable code, jQuery remains a fine tool.

Comment: You are absolutely wrong. Vanilla JS always had a robust support for short and readable code. jQuery was build on top of it. The short and readable code feature you are talking about is chaining. Which is now possible with querySelector on every node just as jquery node except it is vanilla. Can you  please share a snippet that demonstrate your thinking?

Comment: If I quit on JQuery, it will be too soon.